# extensible \vzigzag

Tags: symbols, mathtools, stix

Below is some code adapted from the `mathtools` documentation.  I'd like to have extensible versions of the `\vzigzag` command such that the second line in the command below works as expected.  What would be the easiest way of accomplishing that?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}
\providecommand\given{}

\newcommand\Symbol[1][]{%
    \nonscript\:#1\vzigzag
    \allowbreak
    \nonscript\:
    \mathopen{}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\zigr[1](){\renewcommand\given{\Symbol[\delimsize]}#1}


\begin{document}

$E\zigr{a \given b}$ works.

%$E\zigr[\big]{a \given b}$ does not work.  

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no extensible “zig zag” delimiter.

Comment: @egreg how do I make one?

Comment: There's one in `mathabx`, but it doesn't behave. :-(

Comment: In what sense??

Comment: It has a minimum size that's the same as `\Big`.

Comment: ah, thanks.....  I'll take it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a very satisfying solution, because the zigzag has a minimum size like `\Big`.

This uses `\lfilet` from `mathabx`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> s*[0.4]mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lfilet}{4}{mathx}{"37}{mathx}{"37}

\providecommand\given{}
\newcommand\Symbol{%
  \nonscript\:%
  \expandafter\ifx\delimsize\empty
    \expandafter\big
  \else
    \expandafter\delimsize
  \fi\lfilet
  \allowbreak
  \nonscript\:%
  \mathopen{}%
}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\zigr[1](){%
  \renewcommand\given{\Symbol}#1%
}


\begin{document}

$E\zigr{a \given b}$ (normal)

$E\zigr[\big]{a \given b}$ (big)

$E\zigr[\Big]{a \given b}$ (Big)

$E\zigr[\bigg]{a \given b}$ (bigg)

$E\zigr[\Bigg]{a \given b}$ (Bigg)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Arguably you could add further deviation with \footnotesize{\given} (but it looks frail)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer because I do not really know how the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` magic works, but to tell you that you can draw zigzags of different sizes easily with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\newcommand{\TikzZigZag}[1][0]{\ifcase#1%
\tikz[baseline=0.35em]{%
\draw[line width=0.06em,decorate,decoration={zigzag,segment
length=0.28em,amplitude=0.07em}](0,0)--(0,1em);}%
\or%
\tikz[baseline=0.5em]{%
\draw[line width=0.08em,decorate,decoration={zigzag,segment
length=0.4em,amplitude=0.1em}](0,0)--(0,1.4em);}%
\or
\tikz[baseline=1em]{%
\draw[line width=0.1em,decorate,decoration={zigzag,segment
length=0.65em,amplitude=0.15em}](0,0)--(0,2.4em);}%
\fi}
\begin{document}

$(\TikzZigZag\big(\TikzZigZag[1] \bigg(\TikzZigZag[2]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice, thank you.